# Can't figure out the correct python project files hierarchy

Tags: python

I have a python project with hierarchy kind of like this: (but with more folders under src)

```
ip-rep/
│
├── ip_rep/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── run.py
│   ├── src/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── cli_tool/
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├---- cli_loader.py
├── tests/
│   ├── test_cli_loader
│       ├── test_cli_loader.py
│
├── dockefile
├── bash_start.sh
```

now in the dockerfile I have something like this (simplified):

```
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
ADD ip_rep /app/ip_rep
ADD load_ips.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/load_ips.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "load_ips.sh"]
```

and this is the bash file (again simplified):

```
python ip_rep/run.py
```

and this is an example of an import in run.py file:

```
from ip_rep.src.cli_tool.cli_loader import CliTool
```

When I try to run it I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip_rep/run.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ip_rep.src.cli_tool.cli_loader import CliTool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ip_rep'
```

I can't really understand what I did wrong.
I can't remove the ip_rep in run.py and do only `src.` file because then the tests stop working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't run scripts inside a package. Put your scripts outside of the package. Similar to your `tests/` directory; make a `scripts/` directory at that level, but `run.py` in there, then run things.

Comment: @9769953 Sorry I don't fully understand, so should I create a new dir named `scripts` and put my bash there, and then move the `run.py` to be under `ip-rep` and not `ip_rep`?
And once I create that new scripts dir what do I change in my dockerfile? should I move the whole folder under app and run it from there or move only the file to the app folder?

Comment: No, the bash script is fine. But you need to move the `run.py` script outside of the (inner level) `ip_rep` directory/package. Then set a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in the bash script that points to the outer level `ip_rep` directory (the base directory here). Now the script can properly find and import the (inner) `ip_rep` package, without being part of it itself.

Comment: Also, it looks strange to have a `src` subpackage inside your `ip_rep` top package. I would move everything inside up one level, so that you could make `from ip_rep import cli_tools`.

Comment: You have a `load_ips.sh` in your Dockerfile, but a `bash_start.sh` in your app directory. Are those names correct?

Comment: @9769953 Once I moved `run.py` to the outer scope it worked for me, even without  setting `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in the bash script, so thanks!! Also about the bash file name, yeah they are the same I just missed it when I wrote it pseudo like.
@Lenormju about the src name. You're correct but since most of work is JS the few python projects we have use the same dir hierarchy convection to fit most of our code even if it's not the best practice.

Comment: Good to know that worked. I had drafted an answer (see below), but was waiting to hear about the two `*.sh` scripts confusion. Since they're the same, I guess that doesn't matter, and either name will work in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this structure instead

```
ip-rep/
│
├── ip_rep/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cli_tool/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├---- cli_loader.py
├── scripts/
│   ├── run.py
│
├── tests/
│   ├── test_cli_loader
│       ├── test_cli_loader.py
│
├── dockerfile
├── bash_start.sh
```

(You can ignore the `${SOMEDIR}/` part, but it's needed as example below.)

That moves `run.py` into a separate directory at the same level as the `ip_rep` package directory, but not inside it; similar to the tests.

It also removes the unnecessary `src/` directory, as commented by Lenormju.

Your `run.py` file should now have the import line:

```
from ip_rep.cli_tool.cli_loader import CliTool
```

and your `bash_start.sh` should (at least) have something like

```
PYTHONPATH=app/ip_rep

python app/ip_rep/scripts/run.py
```

It is not unlikely that you don't need to set `PYTHONPATH`, if your bash script is already in the `app/ip_rep` directory: Python will automatically put the current directory on its search path. The script could also then be relative, and the whole thing becomes

```
python scripts/run.py
```

The first variant is just more explicit, and allows for putting the bash script elsewhere.

---

Naturally, the best part is to install the package and script(s) properly, so that they are on the system PATH and PYTHONPATH. That would require something like `pip install .` to be run, with a valid `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` file for the project. With that, the bash script becomes simply `run.py` (just that one line) or even `run`, depending on how you configured things. Of course, "run" is a generic and bad name for a script, but that should be what you could be working towards.